# Rewrite this problem in standard form, as a system of first-order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Let us consider the following initial value problem for a second-order equation:

$$y''= xy'-1/(1+y)   \qquad\text{with}\quad     y(1)=1, \;\;  y'(1)=1$$

I need to rewrite this problem in standard form, as a system of first-order ODEs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Set $y'=z$ and make the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y''= xy'-1/(1+y)   $$$$\qquad\text{with}\quad     y(1)=1, \;\;  y'(1)=1$$
Substitute:
$$u=y, v=y'$$
You have now a system of two differential equations of first order:
$$
\begin{cases}
u'=v \\
v'=xv-\dfrac {1}{1+u}
\end{cases}
$$
Where the  initial conditions are :
$$
\begin{cases}
u(1)=y(1)=1 \\
v(1)=y'(1)=1
\end{cases}
$$